# Error Trying to Use "SET @rownum = 0;" in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I tested this query out in mysql it was fine but when I went to run it in php I keep getting this error.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL    server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank FROM ( SELECT *, (totalWins+(total' at line 1`

This is the php code I have.

```
    <?php

    $sql = "    SET @rownum = 0; ";

    $sql .= "   SELECT *,  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank FROM ( ";

    $sql .= "       SELECT *, (totalWins+(totalPushs*.5)) AS totalPoints, totalWins+totalLost+totalPushs AS totalBets FROM ( ";

    $sql .= "           SELECT *, SUM(win) AS totalWins, SUM(lost) AS totalLost, SUM(push) AS totalPushs FROM ( ";

    $sql .= "               SELECT *, (finalResult = 'Winner') AS win, (finalResult = 'Loser') AS lost, (finalResult = 'Push') AS push FROM ( ";

    $sql .= "                   SELECT " . $db_prefix . "users.userID, userName, ";
    $sql .= "                   IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult ";
    $sql .= "                   FROM " . $db_prefix . "users ";
    $sql .= "                   JOIN " . $db_prefix . "picks ";
    $sql .= "                   ON " . $db_prefix . "users.userID = " . $db_prefix . "picks.userID ";
    $sql .= "                   JOIN " . $db_prefix . "schedule ";
    $sql .= "                   ON " . $db_prefix . "picks.gameID = " . $db_prefix . "schedule.gameID ";

    $sql .= "               ) x ";

    $sql .= "           ) x ";
    $sql .= "           GROUP BY userID ";

    $sql .= "       ) x ";

    $sql .= "   ) x ";
    $sql .= "   ORDER BY totalPoints DESC, totalWins DESC, totalPushs DESC, totalLost ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo $row[rank] . '|' . $row[userName]. '|' . $row[totalWins] . '|' . $row[totalLost] . '|' . $row[totalPushs] . '|' . $row[totalPoints];
        echo '<br>';

    }

    ?>
```

I can get the php code to work without the first line of code

`$sql = "   SET @rownum = 0; ";`

but it won't echo out the rank column.

Is there something I have to do differently to line one of the code when it's in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query` does not support running more than one query at a time. You must first run
`mysql_query("SET @rownum = 0;");`, *then* you can run the rest of your query in a second `mysql_query` call.

Answer (score -1):

Please try tablename.* instead of *

Answer (score -1):

Yes Niet. So you only have to do this:

```
$results = mysql_query('SET @rownum = 0, @rank = 1, @prev_val = NULL;', $localhost);
```

Place this on top of your database select query and it should work.